# Nginx Ingress resource annotation to setup proxy_pass directive

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, proxy, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

When I use nginx as ingress controller for my k8s cluster, specifying an ingress rule automatically creates corresponding configurations in the /etc/nginx/conf.d/ files of nginx pod.

So, it configures proxy_pass directive there to relevant upstream/backend service. And it is http.
For this ingress rule for my service:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  # annotations:
  #  nginx.org/redirect-to-https: "false"
  #  #nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx 
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - test.myapp.com
    secretName: test-tls-secret
  rules:
  - host: test.myapp.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: myui
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /api/
        backend:
          serviceName: myapp
          servicePort: 88
```

By default, it automatically creates this directive for backend in nginx configuration:

```
 proxy_pass http://default-my-ingress-test.myapp.com-myapp-88;
```

But instead, i need it to be https like this:

```
proxy_pass https://default-my-ingress-test.myapp.com-myapp-88;
```

Then only my application will work as that backend accepts https requests only.

Is there any way to modify that proxy_pass directive for a particular backend service for this purpose, using any annotations or something like that via Ingress resource?

---

**EDIT:**

Is there any annotation like that available?

Or Is there any option that I could handle it with a sidecar container in the same pod with the actual `myapp` container?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar requirement very recently where the backend pods expected the request on https.

What you'd need is [ssl-passthrough](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/tls/#ssl-passthrough) feature of nginx controller. You need to start the nginx ingress controller with flag `--enable-ssl-passthrough`. This can be passed as a command line argument to the nginx deployment.

Thereafter, the ingress resource needs to be deployed with the following annotations:

```
kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/secure-backends: "true"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
```

to instruct the controller to send TLS connections directly to the backend.

Comment: Should I specify the `spec.tls` section in the ingress resource along with these annotations?And, Will these setup change the `proxy_pass` directive in configuration to https?

Comment: Yes that remains.
I'm not too sure about the proxy_pass directive, but as you mentioned "my application will work as that backend accepts https requests only" - this configuration instructs the nginx controller to send https requests to the backend and not terminate it at the controller.

Comment: I tried this, but didn't worked. I'm getting `400 (Bad Request)` error, with `net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING ` error in browser while accessing POST request `https://test.myapp.com/api/v4/login`.

Comment: I'm not sure if that error is because of the additional ssl-passthrough annotations. You also need to make sure that the nginx controller started with `--enable-ssl-passthrough` enabled. The pod logs should show something like `"Starting TLS proxy for SSL Passthrough"` during startup.

Comment: I set enable-ssl-passthrough to true via values file and the pod description shows that in args section. But there is no such logs like `Starting TLS proxy for SSL Passthrough` in the pod logs.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this error as similar configuration works for me.